ImportError when unpickling an object in Python 2.7
I have a pickled object of MyCustomClass. It is pickled using Python 2.7.8 builtin pickle module:
# mymodule.py

import pickle

class MyCustomClass:
    def __init__(self):
        attr1 = None

def main():
    with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(MyCustomClass()))

This results to a file begining with:
(imymodule
MyCustomClass
p0
(dp1
S'_MyCustomClass__attr1'
...

I want to unpickle the object using:
with open("file.txt") as f:
    result = pickle.load(f)

No matter where and how I run this code, I always get ImportError: No module named mymodule.
I'm running the Python within a virtualenv and the mymodule.py is in the root project directory.
The question is: What can I do to successfully unpickle the object? I don't mind any code changes if the MyCustomClass object structure (attributes) remains the same.
I have tried running the unpickling code:

from the same file in the if __name__ == "__main__": ...
from another file within the same package
in Python interactive console wrapped in a function
using python -m mymodule
from a method within MyCustomClass


Have you tried importing mymodule.py before unpickling the object?

@chepner Yes, but it has no effect.

Cannot reproduce. import mymodule, pickle; pickle.load(open('file.txt')) produces the original object.

@chepner Does the file.txt start with (imymodule line in your case?

Yes. (This doesn't affect the question much, but you need self.__attr1 = None to make your class definition and file.txt contents agree. Please make sure to provide a [mcve].)
